# Open link in new browser?

Tags: javascript, new-window

I have the following code below in a javascript file and need to have the link that is being generated open in a new window.

```
   if (currentSearchType === 'extSearch') {
  extSearchSearchValue = extSearchSearchInput.val();
  window.location.href = replaceByObject(global.uhg.data['general'].body.extSearchSearchUrl, {
    q: extSearchSearchValue
  });
```

Normally with javascript I believe you'd use a window.open type of function, but not sure how to incorporate that with this type of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a var to hold the URL and then pass it to `window.open()`...

```
if (currentSearchType === 'extSearch') {
  extSearchSearchValue = extSearchSearchInput.val();
  var url = replaceByObject(global.uhg.data['general'].body.extSearchSearchUrl, {
    q: extSearchSearchValue
  });

  window.open(url, 'searchWindow');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

However you do it, opening a new browser window with javascript will most probably be blocked by popup blockers, so perhaps you should rethink your approach to the user himself clicking a regular link, then you can use target="...".

Comment: Probably is a stretch but frequently certainly. Absolutely unreliable expectation is the point. Further to this there's no guarantee of getting a new window vs a new tab anyway.